# Cakephp Auth component malfunctioning

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I got trouble with auth component in cakephp, on ovh host.

When i log in, no session variable are set :
print_r($this_session) only show :

```
Array ( [Config] => Array ( [userAgent] => [time] => 1302122401 [timeout] => 10 ) )
```

The weird part of this issue, is that sometimes it works... I used to connect correctly from my house, less from my work.

Here is the code i use. It really simple.
One app_controller :

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
        var $components = array("Session","Auth");
        function beforeFilter() {
                $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password');
                $this->Auth->loginAction = array('action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'discs', 'action' => 'hello');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
                $this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid name / password combination.  Please try again';
        }
}

?>
```

In user_controller :

```
function login() {
           }

    function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

I try to modify the sessions configuration : 
 - trying php or cake managed
 - trying security level from low to medium
 - trying to change the session cookie name
 - trying set checkAgent to false.

Any idea ?

Comment: try removing everything temporarily from before filter and try it out. if it works.

Comment: If i remove everything from parent filter, it doesn't log me. If i just let Auth->fields set, the behavior is the same as previously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess your code is already correct.
I've noticed the file name 'user_controller'. Is that user_controller instead of users_controller? naming convention in cakephp is really important for us to prevent such errors. Lastly, try to remove `$this->Auth->loginAction = array('action' => 'login');`.